# index-small-if with one or multiple criterias from the same column

Tags: excel, indexing

With help from this forum I got the following array formula together.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SalesOrderLine, SMALL(IF(SalesOrderLine[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId, ROW(SalesOrderLine[SalesOrderId])-1, IF(SalesOrderLine[SalesOrderId]=SalesOrderId2, ROW(SalesOrderLine[SalesOrderId])-1)), ROWS(A$23:A23)), 13),"")
```

Unfortunately this formula is only working when both criterias `SalesOrderId` and `SalesOrderId2`have data. I would like to see the result from first criteria even if second criteria `SalesOrderId2` has no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments below - revised version:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(SalesOrderLine,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SalesOrderLine[SalesOrderId],CHOOSE({1,2},SalesOrderId,SalesOrderId2),0)),ROW(SalesOrderLine[SalesOrderId])-MIN(ROW(SalesOrderLine[SalesOrderId]))+1),ROWS(A$23:A23)),13),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`CHOOSE` function creates an "array" of your two ids. `MATCH` function will still produce valid results when matched against that array, even if some of the values are errors.

Comment: unfortunately still the same issue. The result from first criteria isn't showing up when second criteria is #N/A

Comment: Ok, you didn't say it was an error - do you mean that SalesOrderId2 = #N/A?

Comment: Sorry yes. If `SalesOrderId2` is error #N/A, result for first criteria `SalesOrderId` won't show up.

Comment: OK, you can use `MATCH` which won't break when one of the criteria is an error - I'll revise my suggestion

Comment: thank you for your revise, that works. How would the formula look like if I have more than two criterias? I understand the _IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH......),CHOOSE_ part, but not the _ROW(.......)-MIN(ROW(.....)_ part. I am just asking because at some point I might come accross this cenario with _SalesOrderId,SalesOrderId1,SalesOrderId2,SalesOrderId3,......._

Comment: The only part you'd need to change is the CHOOSE function, so if you have 4 ids it would look something like this: `CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,},id1,id2,id3,id4)` - it would be better if you have a single range with all the ids then you can just replace the above CHOOSE part with `IDRange`